# Making a Chart like this?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a chart like this:
[image]

And my data is organized like this:

[image]

I'm just not sure how my chart needs to be organized in terms of series to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **pivot chart** as opposed to a regular chart in Excel. Pivot charts are closely related to pivot tables and you can find an introduction to them both [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010177384.aspx).

Your data layout is not optimised for pivoting but you can probably generate the memory chart as shown with no changes.